How do I edit my code so that there will only be a single number in the gradient function's applied column?
So I have a dataframe with NaN values and I replaced them with 0 (you will see below).
I tried to calculated the np.gradient per row. I applied the output to a new column, but the column has multiple values in it.
Thereafter I wanted to list the index for where the gradient is negative.
# Replace NaN values with 0
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Function to calculate gradient per row
def calculate_gradient(row):
    gradient = np.gradient(row)
    return gradient

# Apply the function row-wise and add the result to a new column
df['Gradient'] = df.apply(calculate_gradient, axis=1)

#list the index where the gradient column is negative 
negative_gradient_indices = [df['Gradient'] < 0].index.tolist()

print(negative_gradient_indices)

Output :

I was expecting a singular gradient for the whole row. When I list the index the error states that it contains more than one element.

I assume you want to compute the gradient of a complete column of your dataframe.
I designed a dataframe like following :
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[2, 6, 6, np.NaN, 5], columns=['data'])

Then you can apply your function on a column and get the results :
# Apply the function row-wise and add the result to a new column
df['Gradient'] = calculate_gradient(df['data'])

# list the index where the gradient column is negative
negative_gradient_indices = df.index[df['Gradient'] < 0].to_list()

Output :
[2, 3]


np.gradient returns an array with the same size as the input array. Your gradient for each row would be the same size as the input row. You can use
row_index, column_index=np.where(np.vstack(df['Gradient']) < 0)
negative_gradient_indices=np.array([row_index,column_index])

to print out row, and column indexes of negetive indices, which in my example dataframe is like follows.
[[1 0]
 [1 2]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]]


First, note that you don't get a singular value for each row by using the np.gradient, because it uses central difference in the interior points and first difference when it is at the boundaries. So, getting a list of numbers when you apply np.gradient to a row is normal.
Regarding to your code, if you want to search in the list of gradients in the 'Gradient' column of your pandas dataframe and get the index of the rows which have negative values in their list of gradients, you should modify one line of your code where you want to check the negative values as below:
negative_gradient_indices = df[df['Gradient']].apply(lambda x: np.any(x < 0))].index.tolist()

